# How to tab to a specific column from any starting point?

Tags: java, formatting, text-files

I want to be able to reach a specific column of tabs no matter the stating point. I'm creating a text file with some information about integers, and want to display the prime factors last in each row. As it is now the prime factors for each number start at the next tab column from the last word written, which isn't in the straight line I want them to be.

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdOVJ.png) you can see how it currently is. Ugly.

So what I want is to write the prime factors for each number to have their starting points in a straight vertical line. This would require a different amount of tab-steps for each row. Is there any way to reach that line for every row, without knowing the point at which the last previous word ended?

Comment: that depends on how you read your information from the file. How do you have your information now. are you creating a string that you will write in the file?

Comment: It would be better to switch to fixed-width columns of varying width. E.g., String.format("%20s%15s%10d", "hello", "world", 15);

Answer (score 0):

If you are a bit more advanced you can use **Apache POI API** for that thing.
Else it depends on how you create or read your data:
if you have it parsed as a string- you can use **StringTokenizer** using your string as first argument, and your delimeter "\t" as a second arguement.